# Is there a better way to put classes into html and body tags in next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm working with Next.js and Tailwind, and to get some elements displaying correctly I need to put some style classes into `<html>` and `<body>`.

I did this to my `MyApp`

```js
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps}: AppProps) {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.querySelector("html").classList.add("h-full");
    document.querySelector("body").classList.add("h-full");
    document.querySelector("#__next").classList.add("h-full");
  });

  return (
      <Component {...pageProps} />
  )
}
```

That's working... but I would like to know if there any other way of doing, or more elegant solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a `_document.tsx` file with this:

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

export default function Document() {
    return (
        <Html lang="en-us" className="h-full">
            <Head />
            <body className="h-full">
                <Main />
                <NextScript />
            </body>
        </Html>
    )
}
```

[Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/custom-document)

We found this in some Tailwind CSS/Next.js researching and it works for us.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Next.js functional component and this worked for me:

```js
useEffect(
    () => {
        if (modalOpen) {
            document
                .querySelector("html")
                ?.classList
                .add("!overflow-y-hidden");
        } else {
            document
                .querySelector("html")
                ?.classList
                .remove("!overflow-y-hidden");
        }
    },
    [modalOpen]
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it is not in the context since the problem was to apply `h-full` for all the page, not only to a modal as your code shows.